# Is it possible to have logarithmic bins in solr facet ranges, or use a facet range over a logarithmic value of a field?

Tags: solr

I would like to represent my data in logarithmic bins/buckets. Using the JSON API, you can easily specify linear bins: `[0:100[, [100:200[, ...` using facet ranges:

```
price_ranges: {
    type : range
    field : price,
    start : 0,
    end : 1000,
    gap : 100   
}
```

Is is possible to do something like (the example below doesn't work)

```
price_ranges: {
    type : range
    field : log(price),
    start : 1,
    end : 10,
    gap : 1   
}
```

to obtain bins `[1:10[, [10:100[, [100:1000[, ...` ?

It would of course be possible to use intervals to do this, but the example above allows for more flexibility, e.g. easily switching to other functions than a log.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a logarithimic gap and not a logarithmic price? In your example wouldn't the gap be the same (i.e. 1-10, 10-20), but the value would be the log value of the price?

Comment: You are right. But in the end both methods would give me the information I need, so either solution is a good one to me.